# Show icon for file type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem showing different icons for different file types. My code duplicates the icons. Any help?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var icon;
  var arr = $.map($('.link--file'), function(el) {
    var ext = $(el).data('f').split('.').pop();
    if (ext === 'png') {
      img = '<i class="fa fa-circle></i>';
      $('.link--file').append(img)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" data-f="2134.png" class="link link--file">filename1.png</a>
  <a href="#" data-f="432543.png" class="link link--file">filename2.png</a>
  <a href="#" data-f="345.pdf" class="link link--file">filename2.pdf</a>
  <a href="#" data-f="54445.jpg" class="link link--file">filename1.jpg</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.link--file').append` -> `$(el).append`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<div>
   <a href="#" data-f="2134.png" class="link link--file">filename1.png</a>
   <a href="#" data-f="432543.png" class="link link--file">filename2.png</a>
   <a href="#" data-f="345.pdf" class="link link--file">filename2.pdf</a>
   <a href="#" data-f="54445.jpg" class="link link--file">filename1.jpg</a>
</div>
<script>
   var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
   for(let el of link )
   {
   console.log(el.innerHTML.split('.')[1]);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.each()` [(docs)](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to do this. This way you have access to the current element in your loop via `this`.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('div .link--file').each(function() {
    if(this.dataset.f.includes('.png')) {
     $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <a href="#" data-f="2134.png" class="link link--file">filename1.png</a>
   <a href="#" data-f="432543.png" class="link link--file">filename2.png</a>
   <a href="#" data-f="345.pdf" class="link link--file">filename2.pdf</a>
   <a href="#" data-f="54445.jpg" class="link link--file">filename1.jpg</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you append to all `.link--file` elements. Instead you need to append to the specific one within the iteration of the loop.

In addition you should use `each()` to loop through a set of elements in a jQuery object, not `map()`. The latter is intended for use building an array from a collection.

Lastly, you can make the icon lookup logic more extensible by using an object to store the icon classnames you want to use.

```js
let iconLookup = {
  png: 'fa-circle',
  pdf: 'fa-square-o',
  jpg: 'fa-circle-o'
}

jQuery($ => {
  $('.link--file').each((i, el) => {
    let $link = $(el);
    let ext = $link.data('f').split('.').pop();
    if (iconLookup.hasOwnProperty(ext)) {
      $link.append(`<i class="fa ${iconLookup[ext]}"></i>`);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <a href="#" data-f="2134.png" class="link link--file">filename1.png</a>
  <a href="#" data-f="432543.png" class="link link--file">filename2.png</a>
  <a href="#" data-f="345.pdf" class="link link--file">filename2.pdf</a>
  <a href="#" data-f="54445.jpg" class="link link--file">filename1.jpg</a>
</div>
```